# Is it possible to Create a Named Pipe on a remote machine (by IP address)?

Tags: windows, named-pipes

Is it possible to Create a Named Pipe on a remote machine (by IP address)?

Comment: You mean a named pipe in Windows?

Comment: yes i do mean pipe in Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Pipes in windows are not referenced by IP address.

You can create a named pipe for inter-process communication, or, create a winsock TCP socket - which is less popular on windows.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't reference a host by IP address. For completeness: remote hosts are generally possible, you just have to reference the machine by its name. The pipe name is constructed as follows:

```
\\ServerName\pipe\PipeName
```

See [MSDN on Pipe Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365783%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for further reading.